# Group of people that are always there for you

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word which refers to the group of people that are always there for you and supporting you to achieve your goals. In this case it's about friends, family and business relations. Is there a single word for this kind of group?

It's for a title that needs a single word.

Comment: They're your "peeps".

Comment: They are absolutely supportive. Where can I find a group of people like that?

Comment: Is the context professional or personal?  Why not just "supporters"?

Comment: Perhaps, this group is "your supportive community".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these words:

*ALTRUISTS

*BENIGNANTS

*BENEVOLENTS.

I think the 1st. one would be nicely compatible in the situation of your description.

Answer (score 0):

[***Prop***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prop)

**Noun** : something that supports

**Verb** : sustain, strengthen

> ... in Australia, they are **props** of nationalism and a national narrative; in the United States, they play into the cult of the sensational; and to human rights watchers,...

and

> a government **propped up** by the military.

Answer (score 0):

Stalwart is one word that comes to mind. Although it's not one word, could you not use towers of strength or pillars of strength?  If it is only one word that you're looking for then I suggest mainstay.